# Unexpected Behavior with SwiftUI Slide Transition Using Shared Offset

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, geometryreader

I'm experiencing some unexpected behavior with a slide transition in a SwiftUI view.

I have a series of slides within an HStack that I want to animate through when a button is pressed.

I expected that I'd need to calculate individual offsets for each slide to make them appear and disappear correctly.

However, when using the same offset calculation for each slide, the transition still behaves correctly, and I'm trying to understand why.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```swift
struct OnboardingView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = OnboardingViewModel()

    func calculateOffset(_ index: Int, _ screenWidth: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let difference = index - viewModel.currentPage
        return screenWidth * CGFloat(difference)
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            let screenWidth = geometry.frame(in: .global).size.width

            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                SlideView1()
                    .frame(width: screenWidth)
                    .offset(x: calculateOffset(1, screenWidth))
                SlideView2()
                    .frame(width: screenWidth)
                    .offset(x: calculateOffset(1, screenWidth))
                SlideView3()
                    .frame(width: screenWidth)
                    .offset(x: calculateOffset(1, screenWidth))
            }
        }
        .background(Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea())
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
            VStack {
                Text("Current Page: \(viewModel.currentPage)")
                Button("Next") {
                    withAnimation {
                        viewModel.currentPage += 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class OnboardingViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentPage = 1
}

struct SlideView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Slide 1")
    }
}

struct SlideView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Slide 2")
    }
}

struct SlideView3: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Slide 3")
    }
}


class OnboardingViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentPage = 1
}
```

As you can see, calculateOffset(1, width) is used for all slides, yet the view transitions correctly with each button press.

To provide more context, here's an image from the Xcode view hierarchy debugger showing all the slides lined up side by side, which seems to confirm that the layout is as expected for an HStack:

[image: View Hierarchy Debugger Snapshot]

I'm puzzled as to why this works. My expectation was that each slide should have its own offset calculation based on its position in the stack.

Could someone help me understand the underlying mechanics of why the shared offset leads to the correct behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First of all

---

Let's make it a lot more readable and viewable.

```
let screenWidth = geometry.frame(in: .global).size.width
let screenHeight = geometry.frame(in: .global).size.height
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    SlideView1()
        .frame(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
        .offset(x: calculateOffset(1, screenWidth))
    SlideView2()
        .frame(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
        .offset(x: calculateOffset(1, screenWidth))
    SlideView3()
        .frame(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
        .offset(x: calculateOffset(1, screenWidth))
}
```

we can have a check in `Debug View Hierarchy` and that seems to be like that

[image]

## Then

---

we can adjust the code a little bit

```
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    SlideView1()
        .frame(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
    SlideView2()
        .frame(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
    SlideView3()
        .frame(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
}
.offset(x: calculateOffset(1, screenWidth))
```

If we have a check for `Debug View Hierarchy` again, you can find it totally the same.

Every time you click the button, the `HStack`'s position is changed

## Conclusion

---

Your are just adjusting the `HStack`'s position not the `SlideView`'s.

## What's more

---

I think your func `calculateOffset` is not the same you want, you can change it to.

```
func calculateOffset(_ index: Int, _ screenWidth: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let difference = 1 - index
    return screenWidth * CGFloat(difference)
}
```

and make it effect by

```
.offset(x: calculateOffset(viewModel.currentPage, screenWidth))
```

Comment: Ahhh. I see. Adjusting the HStack offset instead of the individual views offset makes sense

Answer (score 1):

It's working because each of the slides is being given the full width of the screen and they are all contained inside an `HStack`. This means, the width of the `HStack` is 3x the width of the screen, so at any time you are only seeing one third of the `HStack`. A `GeometryReader` aligns its content top-leading, so *it is always the first third of the `HStack` that is seen*.

The offset for all slides is being calculated as `screenWidth * (1 - currentPage)`. This means:

- when currentPage is 1, none of the slides have an offset, so the first slide is seen in the first third of the `HSTack` -> OK
- when currentPage is 2, all slides have an offset of one screen's width, so the second slide is seen in the first third of the `HStack` -> OK
- when currentPage is 3, all slides have an offset of two screen's width, so the third slide is seen in the first third of the `HStack` -> OK.

Another way to do it would be to apply the offset to the `HStack` instead. The parameter should still be passed as 1 in this case too, so in fact the parameter is redundant and you can change the function to work without a parameter.